# scraping authentication page with multi form

Tags: scrapy

On the site I want scraping there an authentication page. 
there is no username and password to enter but among twenty click button to select a location.
example the form of a button:

```
<form id="liliForm-2519" name="liliForm-2519" method="post" action="http://exemple.com/rat/body.ayers.verlayer/57">
<input type="hidden" name="t:formdata" value="ERERAAADFDFvzloEVAN3OqfcAA">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Acces">
</form>
```

is that it is possible to simulate the clik for the submit? And if so could someone help me? Thank you in advance STEF

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the clickdata parameter in the FormRequest class:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects

```
def parse_page(self,response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,clickdata={'value':'Acces'})
```

or you can use the formxpath parameter to match a certain xpath.

If you want me to further look into it, feel free to post a link.

Answer (score 0):

with python scrapy you can do something like

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    FormRequest(url=http://exemple.com/rat/body.ayers.verlayer/57",
                method="POST",
                response=reponse)
```

it will retrieve actual values from your html reponse to fill in missing input fields of the form.

Comment: No this won't retrieve actual values from the html response. Instead you have to do FormRequest.from_response(response, url=...)